# I write my own keras layer, but i when build it ,the input shape is None

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

The input code: valuelist contains six tensors which shape is (None,1,128), so the allvalue should be (None,6,128), and query shape is (None,128).

```
allvalue = Concatenate(axis=-2,name="concatenatet")(valuelist)
print("allvalue",type(allvalue),allvalue.shape)
val2 = MyAttention.Attention3(name="attalpall")([query,allvalue,allvalue])
```

The allvalue print result is:

```
allvalue <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> (?, 6, 128)
```

the Attention3 layer build code:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    print(input_shape)
    self.WQ = self.add_weight(name='WQ', 
                              shape=(input_shape[0][-1], input_shape[0][-1]),
                              initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              trainable=True)
    self.WK = self.add_weight(name='WK', 
                              shape=(input_shape[1][-1], input_shape[1][-1]),
                              initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              trainable=True)
    self.WV = self.add_weight(name='WV', 
                              shape=(input_shape[2][-1], input_shape[2][-1]),
                              initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              trainable=True)
    super(Attention3, self).build(input_shape)
```

The input_shape print result is：

```
[(None, 128), None, None]
```

So I get this error when I build my model.

```
shape=(input_shape[1][-1], input_shape[1][-1]),

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It seems query's shape is right, but I don't know why the allvalue becomes None